# Pyspark : RDD cache always serializes data

Tags: apache-spark, caching, pyspark

I went through multiple documents saying that default behavior of performing a cache/persist on a spark RDD stores the RDD as **deserialized objects** to JVM memory

However, when I ran some test using a sample file (5-6 lines), the **Storage Level** under **Storage** section in spark UI always shows as **Memory Serialized 1x Replicated**

Can anyone help me understand if I am missing anything here?

Comment: Hello, what env and Spark version are you using? Can you add your sample code? I did a quick check and for me (Databricks Spark 3.3, and second check with spark-shell on clean Spark build) its as expected so Memory Deserialized 1x Replicated when i just call rdd.cache on sample rdd

Comment: @M_S, I am using **the community Databicks (10.4 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.2.1, Scala 2.12)**  


  **Code I am running**  

  **rddWhole = spark.sparkContext.textFile("/FileStore/tables/Sample.csv")**  
  **rddWhole.cache().count()**  

  **/FileStore/tables/Sample.csv** is a very small file with 5 lines

Comment: @M_S Please note that my example does not intentionally uses dataframe/dataset api but an RDD api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the same test as you, i prepared a small file:

```
id;name;value
1,test,full
2,test,empty
3,test,important
4,test2,sadfdsf
5,test4,gfdsfgdfg
```

Then i started 10.4 databricks community Cluster with Spark 3.2.1 and Scala 2.12 and executed this code:

```
//small files
val rddWhole = spark.sparkContext.textFile("dbfs:/FileStore/shared_uploads/my-email@gmail.com/very_small_csv.csv") 
rddWhole.cache().count()
```

as the result in SparkUI i can see this:

[image]

Same applies for bigger file (screenshot its from 3.3 but its the same)

[image]

Is it exactly the same on your env?

Edit: i can confirm that as stated in comment for Python its serialized.

[image: Python SparkUI]

I checked source code and i can see a difference between Scala and Python. For rdd they both are using MEMORY_ONLY level for caching but it is defined in other way in Python than i Scala

[Scala source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/storage/StorageLevel.scala)

[Python source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/storagelevel.py)

```
val MEMORY_ONLY = new StorageLevel(false, true, false, true) //Scala
StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY = StorageLevel(False, True, False, False) //Python
```

Where the last parameter is deserialized so if think thats why its different but for this moment i am not sure what is the reason

Comment: Thank you once again @M_S for all the responses.
I was able to get the ***same result*** as yours with the same steps. However, the example I was sharing you earlier is using ***python instead of scala***.  I still have the same "Serialized output"  whenever I use python

Comment: Could you please try the above steps again with python.?

Comment: i checked and you are right! I added edit for my answer, it looks like this behaviour is different for Scala and Python api and thats the reason. This is interesting but for this moment i dont know why it was implemented that way

Comment: At least I am not alone seeing this :-) @M_S. Thank you again